# disk I/O error using crhomadb with databricks

Tags: sqlite, databricks, chromadb

I am using chromadb version  '0.4.5'.
I can store my chromadb vector store locally. However, when I tried to store it in DBFS I get the
"OperationalError: disk I/O error" just by running

```py
vector_db_path = '/dbfs/FileStore/HuggingFace/data/demo_langchain/test_vector_db/'
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=vector_db_path)
```

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368204/sqlite-disk-i-o-error-python-databricks) that deals with the same error and the accepted solution there was

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
curr = conn.execute('PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE')
```

Ok, I tried:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect("/dbfs/FileStore/HuggingFace/data/demo_langchain/test_vector_db/chroma.sqlite3")
curr = conn.execute('PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE')
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=vector_db_path)
```

OperationalError: disk I/O error

My guess is, it is most likely a new issue with chromadb, since they recently [switched](https://docs.trychroma.com/migration)  from duckdb to sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out I was using the wrong format for the path.

Databricks offers two formats, e.g.

```
Spark API Format: dbfs:/FileStore/demo_langchain/hf_embed

File API Format:/dbfs/FileStore/demo_langchain/hf_embed
```

Normally both work, but for chromadb only the first one works:

```py
vector_db_path = 'dbfs:/FileStore/HuggingFace/data/demo_langchain/test_vector_db/'
client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=vector_db_path)
```

no need to connect to sqlite directly.